# "request VNRecognizeTextRequest was cancelled" iOS Vision framework

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, apple-vision

I am designing an iOS OCR app using the Vision framework. The app relies on a video feed, which is what the user sees, but it takes photos in the background on a timer to improve the text recognition performance (I use the photos to take advantage of the .accurate setting). My issue is that when I decrease the time interval to less than 3 seconds (and sometimes even at or above 3 seconds), I get a crash telling me that my "request VNRecognizeTextRequest was cancelled." This is the full error message: 
`Error Domain=com.apple.vis Code=1 "request VNRecognizeTextRequest was cancelled" UserInfo={VNRequest=<VNRecognizeTextRequest: 0x283e41dc0> VNRecognizeTextRequestRevision1 ROI=[0.0733333, 0.338831, 0.853333, 0.322339], NSLocalizedDescription=request VNRecognizeTextRequest was cancelled}`

The crash occurs on `try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.requestsForPhoto)` (more context for this code is given below).

My suspicion is that my app is trying to perform VNRecognizeTextRequests faster than it can complete them, and that is what causes the error. I'm hoping that there is a way that I can check whether a previous VNRecognizeTextRequest has been completed before I start on the next, but I haven't been able to discover it.

In more detail, this is how the app works. To start out, I initiate a capture session and add both photo and video output to it:

```
func startCaptureSession() {

        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)

        let deviceInput = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)

        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA), kCIInputSharpnessKey as String: Int(5), kCIInputContrastKey as String: Int(1)] 

        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default))

        guard session.canAddOutput(videoOutput) else { return }
        guard session.canAddOutput(photoOutput) else { return }

        session.addInput(deviceInput)
        session.addOutput(videoOutput)
        session.addOutput(photoOutput)

        session.startRunning()
    }
```

Then I set up the photo capture:

```
    var photoCaptureCompletionBlock: ((UIImage?, Error?) -> Void)?

    func captureImage(completion: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            let settings = self.setupPhotoSettings(for: self.photoOutput)
            //this seems to be where the issue is
            self.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
            self.photoCaptureCompletionBlock = completion
        }
    }

    @objc func captureImage(_ sender: Timer) {
        self.captureImage {(image, error) in
            guard image != nil else {
                print(error ?? "Image capture error")
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

captureImage(_:) is called by a timer:

```
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(captureImage(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Then I add the text recognition requests for both photo and video:

```
    func startTextDetection() {
        let textRectanglesRequest = VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.detectTextHandler)
        textRectanglesRequest.regionOfInterest = normalizedRect
        textRectanglesRequest.reportCharacterBoxes = true

        let textRecognitionRequestVideo = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: self.recognizeTextHandler)
        textRecognitionRequestVideo.recognitionLevel = .fast
        textRecognitionRequestVideo.regionOfInterest = normalizedRect

        let textRecognitionRequestPhoto = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: self.recognizeTextHandler)
        textRecognitionRequestPhoto.recognitionLevel = .accurate
        textRecognitionRequestPhoto.regionOfInterest = normalizedRect

        self.requestsForVideo = [textRectanglesRequest, textRecognitionRequestVideo]
        self.requestsForPhoto = [textRecognitionRequestPhoto]
    }
```

Then I perform the requests inside two separate extensions on the View Controller, each of which is a capture delegate:

```
extension TextDetectionViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
            return
        }

        var requestOptions:[VNImageOption : Any] = [:]

        if let camData = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, key: kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, attachmentModeOut: nil) {
            requestOptions = [.cameraIntrinsics:camData]
        }

        let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation(rawValue: 6)!, options: requestOptions)
        do {
            try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.requestsForVideo)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

extension TextDetectionViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
            if let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData){
                print("Image captured.")
                //converting orientation
                let cgOrientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(uiImage.imageOrientation)
                print(uiImage.imageOrientation.rawValue)
                print(cgOrientation.rawValue)
                guard let cgImage = uiImage.cgImage else { return }
                let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage,
                                                                orientation: cgOrientation,
                                                                options: [:])
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
                    do {
//the crash occurs on the below line:
                        try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.requestsForPhoto)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, knowing when the processing finishes would be a huge help.